# Error on building nextjs app "Error occurred prerendering page "/Loader"

Tags: reactjs, deployment, next.js, vercel

So I was building my nextjs app using `npm run build`, but the build is failing by showing two messages

1. Attempted import error: 'FramebufferTexture' is not exported from 'three' (imported as 'FramebufferTexture').
2. Error occurred prerendering page "/Loader". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

The **Loader.js** file is inside **pages** folder of nextjs app.
The app is perfectly running in development server

Code of the **Loader.js**

```js
import { useRef } from "react";
import { Canvas, useFrame } from "@react-three/fiber";
function Box(props) {
  const mesh = useRef();
  useFrame(() => (mesh.current.rotation.x = mesh.current.rotation.y += 0.01));
  return (
    <mesh {...props} ref={mesh}>
      <boxBufferGeometry attach="geometry" args={[0.8, 0.8, 0.8]} />
      <meshStandardMaterial attach="material" color={"orange"} />
    </mesh>
  );
}

export default Box;
```

Also I'm using this `Box` inside a component `Ammeter` **pages/model_pages** , Like this

```js
     <Suspense fallback={<Box />}>
       <Model position={[-3, -5, 0]} />
     </Suspense>
```

For the full code of this file please refer to
https://github.com/joydeep2001/EngineersWay/blob/master/pages/Loader.js

You can also try to build the project by cloning this repo
https://github.com/joydeep2001/EngineersWay

Thanks!

Comment: You should only include page components under the `pages` folder as [Next.js routing is based on its structure](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction). Move any other components to a different folder.

Comment: yes @juliomalves..When I removed the ./Loader file from pages folder it worked!